# Google Chrome is capturing your screen alert on macOS Sonoma

Tags: google-chrome, screen-capture, privacy, sonoma

I'm using Google Chrome on macOS Sonoma and recently noticed this alert on my top bar.
I checked all Google Chrome tabs and none had any screen share feature in use. I disabled all [Chrome extensions](https://chrome://extensions/). I [turned off](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/turn-screen-sharing-on-or-off-mh11848/mac) screen sharing on my Mac, then quit Chrome, [killed](https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/quit-a-process-actmntr1002/mac) all Google and all Chrome tasks from Activity Monitor and started Chrome again. None of that worked. It's clearly a bug. How to fix it?

I still want the option to share my screen with Google Meet on Google Chrome in the future w/o turning privacy settings off/on every time.

[image: Screenshot of "Google Chrome is capturing your screen" alert on macOS Sonoma]

---

*Note: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/1570crz/did_anyone_notice_google_chrome_is_capturing_your/) should be credited for the screenshot.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's a bug on how Google Meet on Google Chrome interacts with macOS Sonoma security & privacy APIs. I had had a recent meeting there and [shared my entire screen](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9308856) with participants. I suspect when the meeting ended, I just **closed it w/o clicking on "Stop Sharing" first**. Here is the solution that worked for me:

1. Open a new (or old!) [Google Meet](https://meet.google.com/) by yourself
2. Select **Present now** > and **Share** your screen
3. Select **Stop Presenting** or **Stop Sharing**
4. Close the meeting
5. Wait a few seconds and voilà!

Comment: Just saw this issue again and was able to fix it w/o restarting Chrome nos macOS!