# Persistent screen sharing icon in safari after google meet call

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari, screen-sharing

I was on a Google Meet call using Safari, during which I shared my screen. After ending the call, the icon indicating screen sharing persisted. Closing Safari didn't resolve the issue; only restarting seems to fix it. Is there a way to stop screen sharing without having to restart my computer?

[image]

Comment: Possibly related:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/471066/119271

Comment: Thank you @Allan, it is probably related. I have opened new google meet on safari but when I click on share screen it doesn't open it.

Comment: I managed to open the screen sharing but after clicking on stop presenting it's still stuck there.